# Error uploading file via php in aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I want to upload a file to `amazon s3` via `php webpage (php sdk)`. My putobject code shows this problem :

> Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException'

with message '

> Found 1 error while validating the input provided for the PutObject
>   operation: [Bucket] is missing and is a required parameter' in  ..

However, I've entered all parameters as :

```
$s3->putObject([            
'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'], //bucket name
            'Key' => '{$name}',     //file name info    
            'Body' => fopen($temp_file_path, 'r'), //file path  
            'ACL' => 'public-read' ]);
```

whats the problem here?

Comment: Check if $config['s3']['bucket'] is set, call var_dump( $config['s3']['bucket' ) for this.

Comment: ok now i get -  'Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server.' error.

Comment: Each error has explanation. The last one is about credentials. Check it.